# Force log out of backend sessions?

Tags: backend, security, session, logout

I shared an administrator account with a 3rd party solution provider to debug one of the extensions installed in our store. Now that the problem is fixed I changed the account password.

However this doesn't seem to log out existing backend sessions. They are still logged in (via browser cookie) even after I changed the account password.

Is there any way to force a log out of ALL Magento backend sessions?

Comment: Delete files from var/session. i think this will work for you

Comment: @MineshPatel, it will work but which sessions exactly to delete? How to know which sessions are backend sessions? Deleting customer sessions may very well hurt sales.

Comment: That is big question. we can not identify session file which are created from frontend or from backend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a way to find the admin user session file. Please follow below steps to find the admin session files under `Magento_Root/var/session/`:

> Note: below method is use in `*nix` environment with console utility

Connect to you server through `SSH` and change your current directory to `MAGENTO_ROOT` and execute below command:

```
grep -H -r -n "\"user_id\";s:1:\"7\"" ./var/session/
```

That's it, you get the lists of admin session file.

What we did here? Using linux `grep` command we search `"user_id";s:1:"7"` string inside all session files locate under `Magento_Root/var/session` directory.

PS: kindly update **`7`** (administrator id in my case) inside `grep` search string with your administrator id.

You can delete all listed files.

Answer (score 0):

Jayesh Patel's answer is correct, but i want to extend it. If you have e.g. Redis configured and running for session handling, you also have to clear the Redis database which is assigned for sessions.

But attention: This will clear frontend sessions too!

I also restart PHP5-FPM and Apache too, to be on the real safe side, even if it's too much.